# Populate HTML only if data in a field exists

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, if

I have a custom object that I am trying to display using visualforce. Some of the fields in the custom object may not have data. I want to check this and only if the data exists, then print the html to display the field. How can I do that?

Below is the code that I am trying to write, which is giving me syntax error.

```
<apex:repeat var="v" value="{! results }">
    <div class="typeHeader">
         {! v.Name}
    </div>
    <h3>My Field</h3>
    <div class="mystyle">
         {! v.myfield }
    </div>
    {! IF (({! v.URL__c == null}), true, <h3>URL</h3><div class="mystyle">{! v.URL__c }</div>) }
</apex:repeat>
```

As you can see I am trying to display some HTML only if URL__c field has some data in it. Could you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apex:outputtext`, or `apex:outputpanel` to render data conditionally with `rendered` attribute.

example apex:outputText :

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{! v.URL__c != null}" >
<!-- your code -->
</apex:outputText>
```

example apex:outputpanel :

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{! v.URL__c != null}" >
<!-- your code -->
</apex:outputPanel>
```

if you want just plaintext the you can even use `if` formula as follows

`{!if(v.URL__c == null, 'Its Null', 'IT has value')}`

[Reference for apex:Outputtext](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm)

[Reference for apex:OutputPanel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm)